# Xampp and local Wordpress permalinks issue

Tags: html, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, xampp

I know this question was asked before but it seems that nothing helped.

I have a local Wordpress installation and try to use `permalinks`.

What I did in my XAMPP was to open the `conf` file and find

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

so it was activated and no `#` before. Then I searched for

`AllowOverride All`

which was fine too. But none of the permalinks work, I always get an `not found` error.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:** question solved, needed to put the `.htaccess` in the root folder and restart XAMPP

Comment: I suppose you have restarted Apache just to be sure any changes are being applied?

Comment: @amenadiel thank you, somehow I did it again and it worked. Started it before already..